# Real-time streaming cep system with delayed reaction

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams, complex-event-processing

I need help for an archetecture issue.

I develope a cep system based on kafka technology with java.

CEP should have followed characteristics:

- distributed (cluster)
- scalable
- fault-tolerance

CEP should make followed actions:

- create events from different sources, which is actually are multi-partitioned kafka-topics (ETL-part)
- analyze sequences of that events and if they are matched for a special patterns (scenario) put reaction-record to some store (analyze-part)
- every X period query this store to do some communication with a client if it's the time (schedule-part)

During X period if a cancel-event appears, so I remove a reaction record from store.

I created that system using KafkaStreams library. But the archetecture as a result is not so good.

KafkaStreams use RocksDB in backend to store states. There are many problems with managing stores in cluster mode and having a consistent data. Also I cant to make sql-queries to them to resque from iterating every record in store to check if the time for reaction is heppen.

I'm not an architect and I only one who is busy in this task. I was adviced to look at KafkaStreams and Flink for create cep programm. But in fact are these technologies really fit?

There are no question for an ETL-part.
But how can I built an analyze-part and (it's more interesting) query-part? What tools can I use?

I'm grateful for any help and advices

[UPD]

About queries and stores:

1. We need to check if the time to send a communication is heppen. If it's true so communicate with a person: push-message, email or any other chanel.

select
...where event_time + wait_time < now

2. After that we need update that record in store to next message of this scenario (and make this algorithm until the person go to last message of scenario or does the cancel action)

Sequence of scenario A:

ev A -> ev B -> ev C -> **ev D** -----> start scenario -----> ev E or msg c was sent -----> cancel scenario

Messages for scenario A:

- msg a (send after wait_time: 10 minutes)
- msg b (send after wait_time: 1 day)
- msg c (send after wait_time: 7 days) - last

update
... where user_id = xxx and scenario_id = A

3. If action was made in 2nd point, so we also need to update userStore (there are some information about users, including special counters; they are help to not spam the client and no sending messagies to him at night)

update
... where user_id = xxx

I wrote an engine for CEP with some rules, which I save in special store - scenarioStore.

Thus, there are a several stores:

1. initialStore (keep last event in scenario sequencies with message parameters, waiting the time to be sent) - **ev D**
2. scenarioStore (sequences of events by scenarios) - CEP rules
3. messageStore (texts and other properties of messages) - msg rules
4. userStore (information about users)

Comment: Are the queries known in advance, or are they adhoc queries?

Comment: Hi, @DavidAnderson. 
I've updated my post and added some more information about stores. Short answer is - yes, I know the queries in advance. Thanks for your attention of my trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do complex event processing CEP with Kafka Streams. There are even open-source libraries for that [kafkastreams-cep](https://github.com/fhussonnois/kafkastreams-cep).

Kafka Streams framework supports [interactive-queries](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) where you can query your state stores to retrieve required data. You can add a REST layer to make it queryable from REST API. Please, see a code example [WordCountInteractiveQueriesExample](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/6.1.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/WordCountInteractiveQueriesExample.java).

Comment: Thanks, @kikulikov. Yes I also use InteractiveQueries. But in that case it's uncomfortable to update stores because of only readable format. So I need send records to topics with new values to update store, then I should read and update them in KafkaStream with attached store.

Comment: For example, I have KafkaStream thread. It gets events and put in store if it needed (initialStore).

In other part of application I use ScheduleExecutorService to check this store (execute every 30 sec). In that part I use IQ to get initialStore and userStore. When I need to update these stores I must send some records to KafkaStream part. And it may have a side effect. If KafkaStream part didn't read the update records, so in Scheduler part there are unconsistent data.

It looks like a complex and hard to support system.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example, but, perhaps, you could just cast your ReadOnlyKeyValueStore to KeyValueStore to be able to write it from the code. like `((KeyValueStore<Bytes, Bytes>) readOnlyStore).put(key, value);`.